# Field.array union for firebase in flutter not saving list elements with same value

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Database for my mobile application that I developed with Flutter. I want to add a new array to this database. I am adding my data to a list. These data contain the same values. When I use the FieldValue.arrayUnion(stats) code, only elements with different values are added.

The list I made contains the following values;
[0-0-0-0 , 0-0-0-0 ,0-0-0-0 ,0-0-0-0 ].
value of saved firebase is just 0-0-0-0.

Firebase database saves when the values are different.

When I add through the firebase site, there is no problem, but when I do it with flutter, I encounter the above mentioned saving problem. Can you help me? Thanks.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
    {
        stats.add("0-0-0-0");
    }

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("xxxx")
          .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection("xxxxx")
          .doc(xxxxx)
          .set({
        "Lang_1": FieldValue.arrayUnion(xxxxx),
        "Lang_2": FieldValue.arrayUnion(xxxxx),
        "Length": counter,
        "Stats": FieldValue.arrayUnion(stats),
      });
```

my solution.

```
  stats.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    stats.add("0-0-0-0");
  }
  final docData = {
    "x": x,
    "x": x,
    "x": x,
    "Stats": stats,
  };

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("x")
      .doc(x)
      .collection("x")
      .doc(x)
      .set(
        docData,
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior: `arrayUnion` treats the array contents as a set, and only adds the item if it isn't already present.

There is no `arrayAdd` operator, so if you want to add a duplication, you will have to:

1. Read the document in your application code
2. Add the item to the array
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

Also see:

- [Flutter-Firestore: Add Value to Array That Already Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113338/flutter-firestore-add-value-to-array-that-already-exists/76113617#76113617)
- [How do I add equal elements to an array in Firestore in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423352/how-do-i-add-equal-elements-to-an-array-in-firestore-in-flutter)
- [Firestore doesn't store two identical values while updating an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110491/firestore-doesnt-store-two-identical-values-while-updating-an-array)